# What is the mathematical relation between hfe and hie

Tags: transistors

For a transistor connected in CE configuration, what is the mathematical expression that relates its input resistance hie and current gain hfe? I need this because I am designing a transistor amplifier. In my calculations I need the value of hie. The datasheet provides only the hfe value. So, is there any equation to calculate hie from given hfe?

Comment: For audio frequency range you can use this equation $$h_{ie} \approx (hfe+1)*\frac{26mV}{Ie}$$ Where Ie is a quiescent emitter current

Comment: You should mention that 26mV is the thermal voltage when at room temperature. The thermal voltage in general is given by kT/e, where k, T, and e are the Boltzman constant, the absolute temperature and the elementary charge quantum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both quantities (\${h_{fe}}\$ and \${h_{ie}}\$) are linked to one another via the transconductance \${g_m}\$.

**Derivation**:

\${h_{fe}} = \frac{{{I_C}}}{{{I_B}}} = \frac{{d\left( {{I_C}} \right)}}{{d\left( {{I_B}} \right)}}\$,

with

\$d\left( {{I_B}} \right) = \frac{{d({V_{BE}})}}{{{h_{ie}}}}\$.

Therefore:

\$\frac{{{h_{fe}}}}{{{h_{ie}}}} = \frac{{d\left( {{I_C}} \right)}}{{d\left( {{V_{BE}}} \right)}} = {g_m}\$,

with

\${g_m} = \frac{{{I_C}}}{{{V_T}}}\$ (\${V_T}\$: temperature voltage)

(The transconductance \${g_m}\$ is identical to the slope of the \${I_C} = f\left(V_{BE}\right)\$ characteristics.)